# Delphi : Get active user idle time from Service

Tags: delphi, winapi

i'm using this code to get the local idle time from Windows Application
but when i use it on Service it not returning the active user idle time

```
function IdleTime: DWord;
var
  LastInput: TLastInputInfo;
begin
  LastInput.cbSize := SizeOf(TLastInputInfo);
  GetLastInputInfo(LastInput);
  Result := (GetTickCount - LastInput.dwTime) DIV 1000;
end;
```

any idea ?

thanks in advance

Comment: A service doesn't have a particular active desktop user - there could be multiple desktop sessions in progress.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError exactly so i need to know how to get the active desktop user idle time

Comment: There are some comments that might be relevant to your scenario on the [API documentation for GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: what do you want to do with this info?

Comment: what do you want to get if there be several active desktops with different users ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan to detect if user not using the pc then the service can finish all pending tasks quickly without worry of cpu usage.

Comment: @Arioch'The its rare case

Comment: Then why not just track the CPU usage? Or not run your process low-priority,  so any user's program would preempt it?

Comment: @Arioch'The the service will automatically detect the idle time to determine the priority

Comment: If you run your process low-priority, then the system will do it all for you. That's how do it with my CPU intensive background process.

Comment: i didn't know that ,i was doing it manually low or high :) ,,, thanks it works much much better now.

Comment: This is very wrong approach. Am I using my PC while watching a film (really good one, so I never touch input devices for 90 mins), or not?

Comment: @FreeConsulting i think it will only cuz video lagging with very old pcs ,, now with multicore cpus i think such problems will be rare

Comment: Below my TV there lies a small silent computer based on Intel/nVidia Ion2/Atom D535. It is multicore, yes. But it is weaker than some single-core CPUs

Comment: *i didn't know that* I wonder what did you thought priorities were for? If system would not use them when planning CPU shares - there would be no sense to have priorities!

Comment: @Arioch'The i was think that it has to be set high or low manually didn't read about it before

Comment: Well, in every mp3 player or video player I used there was a "priority" option. WinAMP, AIMP, etc. And also think that in a working computer there is not a SINGLE thing that is done manually. Not a single thing. When you launch Task Manager and "manually" change the priority, in reality it is the Task Manager program that at your request calls a procedure that **programmatically** changes the priority. And if Task Manager program does it, it is reasonable guess that any other program including yours can try to set priority too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service runs in a non-interactive desktop in session 0, and so does not have access to information about interactive desktops.

You would need to run a process in an interactive desktop to get that information. And I suppose you could then pass it to your service using an IPC mechanism. Quite what you would do with the information even if you could get at it session 0 I'm not sure. Sessions are isolated.